# Error in my page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng

I am using selenium with page factory method to automate a login page. An error came when I try to run my code.

My complete code is..

```
package com.docmgr.Pages;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.CacheLookup;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
public class LoginPage
{
    WebDriver driver;
    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver=driver;
    }
@FindBy(how=How.NAME,using="username")
@CacheLookup
WebElement username;
@FindBy(how=How.NAME,using="password")
@CacheLookup
WebElement password;
@FindBy(how=How.CLASS_NAME,using="button")
@CacheLookup
WebElement button;
@FindBy(how=How.LINK_TEXT,using="Forgot Password")
@CacheLookup
WebElement fp;
public void login_Doc(String uid,String pas)
{
    username.sendKeys(uid);
    password.sendKeys(pas);
    button.click();
}
}


package com.docmgr.TestCases;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.docmgr.Pages.LoginPage;

import Helper.BrowserFactory;

public class LoginTest 
{
    @Test
    public void chechValidUser()
    {
        System.setProperty("firefox.webdriver.marionette","pathToGeckodriver");
WebDriver driver=BrowserFactory.startBrowser("firefox","54.68.159.876/docmgr");
LoginPage login=PageFactory.initElements(driver,LoginPage.class);
login.login_Doc("jgsdg","123");

    }
}


package Helper;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class BrowserFactory
{
    static WebDriver driver;
    public static WebDriver startBrowser(String browsName,String url)
    {
        if(browsName.equals("firefox"))
        {
            driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        }

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(url);
        return driver;
    }




}
```

Error is:

> FAILED: chechValidUser 
>  org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   Target URL 54.68.159.204/docmgr is not well-formed. 
>  Command
>   duration or timeout: 27 milliseconds 
>  Build info: 
>    version: 'unknown', 
>   revision: '2aa21c1', 
>    time: '2016-08-02 14:59:43 -0700' 
>  System info: 
>    host: 'naveen-Inspiron-3542', 
>   ip: '127.0.1.1', 
>    os.name: 'Linux', 
>   os.arch: 'amd64', 
>    os.version: '4.4.0-45-generic', 
>   java.version:
>   '1.8.0_111'
>  Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
>   
>  Capabilities [{
>   applicationCacheEnabled=true, 
>    rotatable=false, 
>   handlesAlerts=true, 
>    databaseEnabled=true, 
>   version=45.0, 
>    platform=LINUX,
>   nativeEvents=false, 
>    acceptSslCerts=true, 
>   webStorageEnabled=true,
>    locationContextEnabled=true, 
>   browserName=firefox,
>    takesScreenshot=true, 
>   javascriptEnabled=true,
>    cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] 
> Session ID:
>   992a8a4c-efe1-462f-a656-2f8faadf4c06

Comment: Have you added the jar files properly to your test project?

Comment: @TESTasy ya sure

Comment: @TESTasy Error I mentioned there where I need to put this command System.setProperty("firefox.webdriver.marionette","pathToGeckodriver");

Comment: Usually its right before you initialize your driver.

Comment: @TESTasy Please tell me the correct path

Comment: @TESTasy I got  a new error please help me...

Comment: @TESTasy Thank you, I got the error. Now my code is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, You should not put "pathToGekoDriver" in your code. There you should mention the path where the gecko driver is installed like:

```
System.setProperty("firefox.webdriver.marionette", "E:\\Softwares\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: Hai, Everyone I got the error. I didn't add the protocol. http://......                              and Thank you every one for the contribution